# Select option in drop down menu using WebBrowser does not work

Tags: .net, vb.net, select, browser

```
<select class="question">
    <option value="">Select one</option>    
    <option value="1">Cool</option>
    <option value="2">Good</option>
</select>
```

He tried to give the code did not work

```
WebBrowser1.Document.All("question").SetAttribute("Value", "2")
```

Answer (score 0):

the best method to access an element is by using either its name or its id. you can set the name or id of the select and then try to access it.

```
    <body name="bdy">
    <select name="question">
<option value="">Select one</option>    
    <option value="1">Cool</option>
    <option value="2">Good</option>
    </select>

    webbrowser1.document.bdy.question.SetAttribute("Value","2");
```

or you can also set its id and then try...

```
 <select id="question">
<option value="">Select one</option>    
    <option value="1">Cool</option>
    <option value="2">Good</option>
    </select>

    webbrowser1.document.getElementById("question").SetAttribute("Value","2");
```

hope this works. :)

Comment: Not Work
I did not ID
here all code

<span class="inputcontent">
<select class="question">
    <option value="">Select one</option>    
    <option value="1">Cool</option>
    <option value="2">Good</option>
</select>
</span>

Answer (score 0):

What about this one

```
var question=document.getElementById("question");
question.selectedIndex=2;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: sari sir mooditu ponga